# Missing attributes on "ComponentFactoryResolver deprecated" new implementation?

Tags: angular

From Angular 13 `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated. I fail to find a solution where I can replace it correctly since old `rootSelectorOrNode` parameter is missing from the new solution.

**I would like to create `RectComponent` dynamically and bind it to an on the fly created SVG rect element.**

This is my old solution:

```
public createRectComponent(representation:Shape<SVGRectElement>, viewContainerRef?:ViewContainerRef|null, vcrIndex?:number):ComponentRef<RectComponent>{
    const rectNode:SVGRectElement = representation.element || this.renderer.createElement('rect', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg') as SVGRectElement;
    representation.element = rectNode;
    const rectComponentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(RectComponent);
    viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef || this.artAccessVcr;
    const rectComponentRef = rectComponentFactory.create(viewContainerRef!.injector, [], rectNode);
    viewContainerRef!.insert(rectComponentRef.hostView, vcrIndex);
    return rectComponentRef;
}
```

New way should look like this:

```
    ...
    const rectComponentRef = viewContainerRef!.createComponent(RectComponent, {
      injector: viewContainerRef!.injector,
      projectableNodes: [],
      //rootSelectorOrNode: rectNode //This attribute is missing completly
    });
    ...
```

I could not find anything helpful about this in the documentation but I think it should not be a specific problem because a lot of third party library provides a predefined html node that you can use to bind your angular logic. This is not the case here but still I would prefer to define the svg node element myself as well.

Thank you for your time and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using new [createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent) function which allows you to pass `hostElement` as part of `options`

```
import { EnvironmentInjector, ... } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private envInjector: EnvironmentInjector, ...) {}

...
const rectComponentRef = createComponent(RectComponent, { 
   environmentInjector: this.envInjector,
   hostElement: rectNode 
});
```

[**Stackblitz Deprecated Version with ComponentFactoryResolver**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9smdy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

**[New Version with createComponent](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwmbuy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

It might be **helpful:**

```js
import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('view1', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vc1!: ViewContainerRef;

export class FruitComponent {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }
  
  async loadComponent() {
    this.vc1.clear();
    let { LycheeComponent } = await import('./lychee/lychee.component');
    let f = this.vc1.createComponent(LycheeComponent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps note that the ts file contains both a `Component` and `NgModule` ([see also](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/lazy-loading/components/lazy-loaded/lazy-loaded.component.ts))